# removing cache from command line in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

I want to remove cache from my code. My code is in Ruby on rails. The issue is that i have updated my design but it is displaying the older one.
I tried this `Rails.cache.clear` command but its not working .
It is giving me this error `'Rails.cache.clear' command not found.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to ./config/environments/production.rb or development.rb depending where do you launch your code, and change settings to reflect this :

```
 # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = false
```

and if necessary, comment out your cache store line :

```
# Use a different cache store in production
  config.cache_store = :dalli_store
```

Ideally the first snippet should be enaught.

Comment: You mean there is no way i can remove cache from command line?

Comment: Since the command is no found, I am not sure this is the right way in your version of Rails. Therefore it seems simpler to actually check if cache is the problem in the first place by disabling it. Also reset your terminal, or web server to make sure the issue is not there. This should be much faster way, then figuring out why Rails clearly doesn't allow you to execute command under question.

Answer (score 8):

`Rails.cache.clear` needs to be ran from the Rails console.